# Magento does not display all products within the categories

Tags: magento, csv, e-commerce, categories, product

I have set up the categories and imported the products CSV into Magento, which all worked fine. Each category is display the correct amount of products within the backend. However on the frontend, Magento does not display all of the products in the categories, only the first few. All products are set to be in stock and all have a quantity of at least 1.

[Example Screenshot (Bloch Category)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WTKVz.png)

As you can see the category 'Bloch' has 2233 products. However on the frontend, Magento is only display 6. Screenshot below.

[Bloch Frontend Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KJs18.png)

Can anyone help as to why this might be happening?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Be sure to run the indexes after you update your catalog.  You can do this via command line if you are comfortable doing that.  SSH into the server and cd into the directory of your site.  Once there you can run the command
$ php shell/indexer.php --reindexall

That will fix the issue if its been a while since things were indexed.

If that does not work, you need to check the visibility of the products, they can be set to not visible individually.  Obviously that would prohibit them from being displayed on the front-end.

Lastly, check to see if the stock status is in-stock and the product is enabled.

Typically its one of them that is the culprit.

Comment: Hi there, thanks for the answer. I have re-indexed the site multiple times was checking all of the above. Each product is set as visible, enabled and in stock. I even tried changing the visibility to none and then back to visible. Still no joy.

Comment: Can you access the products using the magneto path or the seo url. If so it sounds like an issue with the category settings, not the products themselves.

Comment: The only thing I can see by some testing just now is validate that the category has the products set as a product from the manage category page for the category you are setting up.  There is a System->configuration->catalog->catalog->frontend that you may need to adjust Some values to make it work they way you expect. After that red run the indexes to catch up with the changes. If that does not work you may have a code issue. This is out of the box functionality and should work.